# What does it mean by saying " rxjs observable" takes multiple where promise doesn't

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, es6-promise

I know how promises and `observables` work but I am not sure when people say that observable can multiple event while `promise` takes only one event at a time.

I looked up on internet but I am not able to find a definition with example to understand what it exactly means.

Comment: once a promise becomes fulfilled or failed, then it's done. but for the observable pattern, every time that observable makes a change, subscribers will be getting notified each time.

Comment: But that's the one fundamental conceptual difference between both types. Some [theory](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Observable can emit different values at different times, a Promise can only resolve to one value at one time (and then never again).

Simple illustration:

Let's try to get three asynchronous results: "a", "b" and "c", each with a delay of 1 more second. With an observable, this could be done like this:

```
var result = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => observer.next("a"), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => observer.next("b"), 2000);
    setTimeout(() => (observer.next("c"), observer.complete()), 3000);
});
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The above will result in this output, each line appearing 1 second later than the previous:

```
a
b
c
```

If you try to do this with one(!) promise, it will not work:

```
var result = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("a"), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => resolve("b"), 2000);
    setTimeout(() => resolve("c"), 3000);
});
result.then(x => console.log(x));
```

This will only output one result (after 1 second):

```
a
```

Even though there was an attempt to resolve the promise also with "b" and "c", that doesn't work: a promise can only resolve once. All subsequent calls to `resolve` are ignored.

An observable however can emit several times, and each time with a different value.

A promise is great when you need one (possibly complex) asynchronous result. An observable is more appropriate when you expect a series of asynchronous results.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, a promise resolves to a value or rejects to an error.

Observable on the other hand is a wrapper for a stream of values that may be distributed across time. For example, an observable bound to mouse click or to a websocket

In angular, the http get observable behaves `like*` a promise in that it only returns a single value.

I am sure someone can guide you to more in-depth explanations, but this essentially is the crux of things.